# Python: return list of sequentially occuring common items from lists and also a list of uncommon ones

Tags: python, list

```
lists = [[a,b,c,d],[a,b,c,d,e],[a,b,c,x],[a,b,c,d,e,f]....lots]

common_items = [a,b,c]
uncommon_items = [[d], [d,e], [x], [d,e,f]]

common_elements(lists[0],lists[1])

def common_elements(list1, list2):
    return [element for element in list1 if element in list2]
```

lot of the answers on SO only able to do this with two lists at a time. need one that can handle any number of lists, and returns two lists.

Note: Order of list is important which leaves out sets.
Note: Must be lowest common items from each list, not based on the just the first list in lists.

Comment: And the code you have so far is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution preserves the order as well.

```
common, uncommon = lists[0], lists[0]
for clist in lists:
    common = [item for item in common if item in clist]
uncommon = [[item for item in clist if item not in common] for clist in lists ]
print common, uncommon
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'b', 'c'] [['d'], ['d', 'e'], ['x'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

**Edit:** As per OP's request in the comments

```
common = lists[0]
from itertools import takewhile
for l1, l2 in zip(lists, lists[1:]):
    common = [i[0] for i in takewhile(lambda i: i[0] == i[1] == i[2], zip(l1, l2, common))]
uncommon = [clist[len(common):] for clist in lists]
print common, uncommon
```

Comment: very good but same as previous answer it doesn't seem to return the lowest common elements. for example, it gives me [a,b,c,d] as the common, where it should've been [a,b,c]

Comment: @ILovePython It returns only `['a', 'b', 'c']` for the input data you provided in the question.

Comment: try this: `[['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f']]`

Comment: returns `>>> lists = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
>>> gen_lowest_common_items(lists)
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f']] `a,b,c,c,d` is not the lowest common items that occurs in that order. order is important, I expected `a,b,c`

Comment: @ILovePython Finally understood what you were saying. Check my answer now.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use sets, but you will lose ordering.

```
lists = [['a','b','c','d'],
         ['a','b','c','d','e'],
         ['a','b','c','x'],
         ['a','b','c','d','e','f']]

sets = map(set, lists)
common = set.intersection(*sets)
uncommon = [s-common for s in sets]
print common    # set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
print uncommon  # [set(['d']), set(['e', 'd']), set(['x']), set(['e', 'd', 'f'])]
```

Sets are the best way to represent common elements. You can maintain the order of uncommon elements by using a different lists comprehension.

```
uncommon = [[x for x in l if x not in common] for l in lists]
print uncommon  # [['d'], ['d', 'e'], ['x'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Assuming the elements of `common` appear in the same order in all lists, you can then convert the common set to a list.

```
common = [x for x in lists[0] if x in common]
```

Comment: the ordering is important for me.

Comment: the ordering of the common is important too

Comment: Why does order matter?

Comment: because the `lists` all maintain order, the returned result's order is important.

Comment: Edited with a conversion from set to ordered list.

Comment: this doesn't seem to return the lowest common elements. for example, it gives me [a,b,c,d] as the common, where it should've been [a,b,c]

Comment: It gives me the correct output. Make sure you are using the same input data as I am.

Comment: try this: `[['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f']]`

Comment: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], [[], ['e', 'f']]` - as expected.

Comment: returns `>>> lists = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
>>> gen_lowest_common_items(lists)
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], [[], ['e', 'f']]]`

Comment: `a,b,c,c,d` is not the lowest common items that occurs in that order. order is important, I expected `a,b,c`

Answer (score 0):

Well I will do it this way...

**Code:**

```
def lcs(l,key=None):
    if key==None: key=min(l,key=len)
    t = [x for x in l if key in x]
    return key if t == l else lcs(l,key[:-1])

if __name__=='__main__':
    lists = [['a','b','c','d'],
             ['a','b','c','d','e'],
             ['a','b','c','x'],
             ['a','b','c','d','e','f']]

    l = [''.join(item) for item in lists]
    print lcs(l)
```

**Output:**

```
abc
```

Well I dont know much about complexity and such, but this code can solve the problem.

Hope this helps  :)